# SQL Rank function over same rank

Tags: sql

I am trying to use SQL function Rank() to get a list the pattern rank of several columns.

Trying with this but it still give continues rank for rows where Mark column is 1.
it gives 0 correclty.
rank() over (partition by (case when mark= '0' then '0' end), id order by date asc, case when mark = '0' then '0' end) end as rank

Here is what I would need to get:

| ID | Date | Mark | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| test | 2022-11-17 | 1 | 1 |
| test | 2022-11-18 | 1 | 2 |
| test | 2022-11-19 | 0 | 0 |
| test | 2022-11-20 | 0 | 0 |
| test | 2022-11-21 | 1 | 1 |
| test | 2022-11-22 | 0 | 0 |
| test | 2022-11-23 | 1 | 1 |
| test | 2022-11-24 | 1 | 2 |
| test | 2022-11-25 | 1 | 3 |
| test | 2022-11-26 | 0 | 0 |
| test | 2022-11-27 | 1 | 1 |
| test | 2022-11-28 | 0 | 0 |
| test | 2022-11-29 | 1 | 1 |
| test | 2022-11-30 | 1 | 2 |

Comment: You are spamming tags and should format the code properly. And your data is junk.

Comment: MySQL <> SQLite - please re-tag correctly.

Comment: What are you trying to rank? Also probably need to show sample input data as well as your sample desired result?

Comment: There are no repeated value in the list, so you could use `ROW_NUMBER()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably a simpler query but this one will do:

```
select id, date, mark, 
  case when mark = 0 then 0 else sum(mark) over(partition by g order by date) 
  end as rk
from (
  select *, sum(i) over(partition by id order by date) as g
  from (
    select *, case when mark = 1 and lag(mark)
                                     over(partition by id order by date) = 0 
                   then 1 else 0 end as i 
    from t
  ) x
) y
order by id, date
```

Result:

```
 id    date        mark  rk 
 ----- ----------- ----- -- 
 test  2022-11-17  1     1  
 test  2022-11-18  1     2  
 test  2022-11-19  0     0  
 test  2022-11-20  0     0  
 test  2022-11-21  1     1  
 test  2022-11-22  0     0  
 test  2022-11-23  1     1  
 test  2022-11-24  1     2  
 test  2022-11-25  1     3  
 test  2022-11-26  0     0  
 test  2022-11-27  1     1  
 test  2022-11-28  0     0  
 test  2022-11-29  1     1  
 test  2022-11-30  1     2
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/foYk6ckf).

Comment: Thank you for answer but for some reason it give me syntax error case when mark = 0 then 0 else sum(mark) over(partition by g order by date) <- syntax error. when I remove order by date the query runs but don't rank

Comment: Are you sure you are using MySQL?

Comment: ignore, works as charm, that was my mistake :)